# Obtain client's MAC address using Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, automation

I'm working on a project that will allow my home automation identify who is at home by using their MAC addresses as an identifier.

I've tried to obtain the MAC address of a client on my own network using Nodejs and the NPM module 'arped'

```
var arped = require('arped');

console.log(arped.table());
```

It reads the ARP tables though it only outputs a handfull of IPs/MACs. Is there something that I'm missing about ARPs or what?

The output is showing my router, my chromecast, my windows laptop and my iPhone 4. It's not showing another windows laptop and an iPhone SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My biggest issue was getting a response from iDevices that went into sleep mode. I worked out you could ping the sync port 62078 and this would always respond regardless of state (unless switched off)

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when running following from command line:

```
arp -h
```

Do you get all MACs or same list you get from node.js?
The ones you don't see might be on different subnet and you will not get MAC address for them.

Comment: `arp -h` doesn't work, but `arp -a` does and it shows the same IP's I get through the other way.

I'm on Ubuntu by the way.

Weirdly, they are all on the same subnet.

Comment: You are right, I mistyped the option. You might get some separation on link layer. Maybe some of them are on WiFi and some of them are connected by cable?

Comment: Also note that arp table contains only addresses of devices you communicated with. Try to ping to device you don't see and then check arp table. It is just a cache of physical addresses so your computer doesn't have to ask for it again and again. It goes like: you try to communicate with remote machine, you use IP address, then your network layer sends it to link layer, which needs to translate IP address into MAC address. It does it by sending broadcast message on network and using response it gets. In orders to reduce number of broadcasts, computers are caching such responses. In ARP table.

Comment: OK, yes that is now working for the IP addresses that I ping. Would you know of a better way to see when people join my network? I could constantly ping a range of IP addresses to update the ARP table but that seems very inefficient.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have few options here:<br>
- ping your devices by name. You will know they are alive from the ping response. This requires functioning DNS resolving.<br>
- without DNS assign your devices static IP addresses. It will be more complicated from device management point.<br>
- obtain information from you router.<br>
- have clients to authenticate on predefined web page on your server or ping your server.

Comment: I think I might just have to go the static IP route. I appreciate your help. Thank you.